# Could collection functions be directly used as methods from the types they support, in F#?

Tags: f#

This is a question purely out of curiosity:

let's say I have this object:

```
let a = [1; 2; 3; 4]
```

I could get the max value by doing:

```
a |> List.max
List.max a
```

but would anything prevent setting it as:

```
a.max
```

similarly, if I want a sorted list and then take the top 2 results:

```
a |> List.sort |> List.truncate 2
```

but what about:

```
a.sort.truncate(2)
```

I know it's not idiomatic of F#, but since the libraries are there, why isn't this allowed as well? I'm curious if there is a clear reason why this wasn't enabled as an option.

Answer (score 5):

Via the [FSharp.Core.Fluent-4.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Core.Fluent-4.0) package you can do this.

F# 5 script:

```
#r "nuget:FSharp.Core.Fluent-4.0"
open FSharp.Core.Fluent

let a = [1..10]

printfn $"{a.max()}"
printfn $"{a.map(fun x -> x + 1)}"
printfn $"{a.filter(fun x -> x % 2 <> 0)}"
```

It's not a default option for F# because it was never a design goal to offer an alternative "view" over the same collection functions. If this is of interest to you, you can file a suggestion in the [language and core library suggestions repo](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+sort%3Aupdated-desc) and discuss with community contributors.

Comment: I don't think it would be necessarily good to add since we'd end up with code harder to read if there are multiple ways; but sometimes, for simple things it would be convenient. For example a.max() is definitely very readable despite not being idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit surprised no one mentioned [Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?view=netcore-3.1), which let's you do exactly that and is a standard library

```
open System.Linq
let a = [1..10]
a.Where(fun x -> x < 8).Take(3).ToArray()
a.Max()
a.Sum()
```

Comment: Note that you’d typically lose specificity though: i.e. `SomeSortedCollection.max` would need to look at e.g. only the ‘head’ or could do some specific search while Linq would typically do a full scan.

Answer (score 1):

One problem with fluent style methods in F# is that it interferes with the type inference model. In toy examples it works because the data and type is typically defined in the same block.

```
a |> List.max //a inferred to type List<'T>
a.max() //F# complains that a type annotation is required
```

You will often encounter these type of issues when working with e.g. strings and its methods like `.ToUpper()`